# R: Convert string (digit with K/M/G suffix) to double

Tags: r

I have data in the following form:

| time | V.out. | V.in. | Resistor1 | Resistor2 | Offset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0,00000000000000e+00 | -1,498494e-05 | 0,00000000 | 10 | 1M | -3 |
| 4,91362656238765e-09 | 3,082234e-02 | 0,03086832 | 10 | 1M | -3 |
| 4,99663437488765e-09 | 3,134312e-02 | 0,03138962 | 10 | 1M | -3 |
| 5,00000000000000e-09 | 3,136424e-02 | 0,03141076 | 10 | 1M | -3 |
| 0,00000000000000e+00 | -7,485015e-03 | 0,00000000 | 10.01K | 1M | -3 |
| 4,90874374988765e-09 | 7,887614e-03 | 0,03083766 | 10.01K | 1M | -3 |

The data is read via `readr::read_delim()` where the columns containing metric prefixes (K = 10^3, M = 10^6 etc.) are read as characters. Is there a way to convert these values to the correct numeric ones? ie.: `10.01K = 10.01 * 10^3`or `1M = 1 * 10^6`.

Raw Data:

```
time;V.out.;V.in.;Resistor1;Resistor2;Offset
0,00000000000000e+00;-1,498494e-05;0,00000000;10;1M;-3
4,91362656238765e-09;3,082234e-02;0,03086832;10;1M;-3
4,99663437488765e-09;3,134312e-02;0,03138962;10;1M;-3
5,00000000000000e-09;3,136424e-02;0,03141076;10;1M;-3
0,00000000000000e+00;-7,485015e-03;0,00000000;10.01K;1M;-3
4,90874374988765e-09;7,887614e-03;0,03083766;10.01K;1M;-3
4,99663437488765e-09;8,162769e-03;0,03138962;10.01K;1M;-3
5,00000000000000e-09;8,173305e-03;0,03141076;10.01K;1M;-3
0,00000000000000e+00;-9,966757e-03;0,00000000;20K;1M;-3
```

Comment: Do the suffixes K and M have meanings?

Comment: Yes. They are the usual metric prefixes. M = 10^6, k = 10^3 etc. (Clarified the question.)

Comment: So `10.01K`= `10.01*10^6`?

Comment: `10.01K = 10.01*10^3` , but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be approached like this: first, you subset the vector on those values whose last character is `K`, using `sub` remove the suffix, convert the result to type numeric with `as.numeric`, and mutiply it with `10^3`. As a final step, you convert the whole vector to numeric.

```
x[grepl("K$", x)] <- as.numeric(sub("K$", "", x))*10^3
x <- as.numeric(x)
[1]       10 10000000 10010000
```

And likewise for the suffix `M`

Data:

```
x <- c("10", "10.01K", "20K")
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way (or even benefit??) of doing this with `stringr`?

Comment: In `stringr` (no benefit though): `x[str_detect(x, "K$")] <- as.numeric(str_replace(x, "K$", ""))*10^3`(warning can be dismissed)

Comment: If the answer helped pls consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: If an answer is a likely duplicate, please consider searching first.